# Identificar de varios botones, cuál se ha presionado, para agregar ese producto al carrito en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, dom, eventos

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compras. Tengo varios productos, pero no sé cómo puedo identificar qué botón se presionó para agregar ese producto al carrito. Lo primero que hago es hacer una clase, llamada Producto, que va a contener todos los productos.

```
class Producto {
    constructor(id, descripcion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
}
let productos = [];
let carrito = [];

productos.push(new Producto("751100", "Manija"));
productos.push(new Producto("851100", "Manija"));
productos.push(new Producto("751200", "Manija"));
productos.push(new Producto("753100", "Manija"));
```

Luego de eso, obtengo con el método `getqueryselector()` el elemento que quiero sumarle el innerHTML. Luego, por cada producto que definí arriba, se hará una card. (No adjunto los estilos porque quedaría muy largo)
El código es:

```
let section = document.querySelector('.tiendaOnline.row.separar.container-fluid');

for (const producto of productos) {
    let article = document.createElement("article");
    article.className = "col col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 carta"
    article.innerHTML = `   <img src="../imagenes/ft-nosotros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Imagen de Producto">
                            <div>
                            
                            <h3 class="codigo">${producto.id}</h3>
                            <p class="descripcion">${producto.descripcion}</p>
                            <p>Precio</p>

                                <div>
                                    <div class="btnCompra">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                            </svg>
                                    <a href="" id="carrito" class="${producto.id} producto">Agregar al Carrito</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="" id="detalles${producto.id}" class="btnDetalles">Ver detalles</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
    // Agregar a sección y no al documento
    section.appendChild(article);
}
```

El problema es que tengo que buscar una forma de saber qué botón está siendo apretado, para poder obtener el ID o la clase de ese producto (El ID del elemento va a ser el mismo que el ID del producto), para, con un push, poder agregarlo al array. No sé, o no conozco otra forma de hacerlo, pero si hay alguna más fácil, es bienvenida. Lo que yo traté de hacer es esto, pero no funcionó, sólo con el primero.

```
let producto = document.getElementsByClassName("producto");
producto.onclick = function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    carrito.push(event.target)
}
console.log(carrito);
```

Mi HTML es:

```
<section class="tiendaOnline row separar container-fluid">
</section>
```

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se busca por `getElementsByClassName` para añadirle un evento hay que recorrer todos los elementos que tiene. Sería algo así en tu caso:

```
let producto = document.getElementsByClassName("producto");

for (var i=0; i < producto.length; i++) {
  producto[i].onclick = function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    carrito.push(event.target)
  }
}
```

Por otro lado, ahora mismo tienes puesto el ID de producto como una clase en "Agregar al Carrito". Es más fácil que lo pongas como ID y no repitas en todos los productos el `id="carrito"`. Cambia por algo así:

```
<a href="" id="${producto.id}" class="carrito producto">Agregar al Carrito</a>
```

Con esto podrás conseguir de manera fácil el botón que se ha pulsado ya que, en `event.target`, existe una propiedad `id` que tendrá el ID de tu producto:

```
carrito.push(event.target.id)
```

Nota: También lo podrías obtener dejando el código como está, pero tendrías que buscar entre las clases del botón y es algo menos natural.

Nota 2: Si en vez de usar un elemento `<a>` usas uno `<button>` no haría falta usar el `event.preventDefault();`

Espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Lo que hice fue agregar eso que me dijiste dentro de mi for of y quedó perfecto. Saludos!

Comment: Fenomenal! Me alegro! 